# Combine separate timeseries into Tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a list of timeseries pandas datasets and apply `tf.metas.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array` to each, then use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` and `ds.interleave(lambda x: x, cycle_length=1, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` to concatenate them into one. This results in an object of type `tensorflow.Python.data.ops.dataset_ops.ParallelInterleaveDataset`.

This appears to be slowing down my training by applying the mapping when it is used. How can I better combine these datasets and result in a `tf.data.Dataset` instance?

Specifically, I have separate `n-`dimensional timeseries data corresponding to different states, and wish to generate as many non-overlapping examples of the following pairs: `m` consecutive events as inputs, with the subsequent event to be predicted. Then the training inputs will be all the `m x n` sequences, and the targets will be the corresponding `1 x n` events.

Comment: One way to improve the performance of your pipeline is to convert the Pandas DataFrames to TensorFlow tf.data.Dataset instances before applying the timeseries_dataset_from_array function and concatenating them. This way, you can avoid the overhead of converting the DataFrames to NumPy arrays and then to TensorFlow tensors, which happens when using the timeseries_dataset_from_array function.

Answer (score 0):

Following up from my comment above;

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create a list of Pandas DataFrames
df_list = [df1, df2, ...]

# Convert the DataFrames to TensorFlow datasets
ds_list = [tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df.values) for df in df_list]

# Concatenate the datasets
concatenated_ds = tf.data.Dataset.concatenate(ds_list)

# Apply the time series dataset function
sequence_length= m
ds = tf.data.experimental.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    concatenated_ds,
    sequence_length=sequence_length,
    targets=concatenated_ds.skip(sequence_length),
    sequence_stride=1,
    shuffle=True)
```

This is an example on how to convert the instances and then concatenate them.

Following below is another example of how you can process each dataset **separately** and then combine the resulting datasets:

```
ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data1)
ds2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data2)
ds3 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data3)

# Process dataset1
ds1 = ds1.map(preprocess_fn, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds1 = ds1.interleave(lambda x: x, cycle_length=1, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds1 = ds1.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# Process dataset2
ds2 = ds2.map(preprocess_fn, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds2 = ds2.interleave(lambda x: x, cycle_length=1, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds2 = ds2.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# Process dataset3
ds3 = ds3.map(preprocess_fn, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds3 = ds3.interleave(lambda x: x, cycle_length=1, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds3 = ds3.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# Use concatenate method to combine the datasets
combined_ds = ds1.concatenate(ds2).concatenate(ds3)
```

Another alternative is to use tf.data.Dataset.zip(ds1,ds2,ds3) that will zip the datasets and return a single dataset with the same number of elements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your comment and answer. The separate datasets are distinct and so we should not allow the input vectors to contain elements from multiple datasets. I need the input-forecast pairs to be generated for each dataset before combining them all together. I believe that you comment is still helpful and applies but that your answer assumes the datasets can be first concatenated together?

Comment: my previous answer did assume that the datasets could be concatenated together. If the datasets are distinct and should not be mixed together, then you will need to process them separately and then combine the resulting datasets. I will be adding an edit to my answer shortly

Comment: I have added another section to the answer above, let me know if that helps

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. One detail is that because I have a list of datasets, a priori I do not know how many there are and in particular they are not saved as variables ```ds1``` etc. How would be best to do this on a list of datasets rather than via explicitly defined  variables?

Comment: In that case you could use a loop to process them and then a) take the tensor slice, b) run map, c) interleave, d) prefetch and finally e)append and end the loop. Afterwards create another loop for the concatenation.